# How to pass variables to html page in nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, nodemailer

I want to send an email with html template.
In that template I want to add few dynamic data while sending the email.

Like my html page having one link, but I want to add one id inside the link.

Is it possible to add dynamic data in html data while sending email, if it is, please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 5):

yes, just build the string for the html before sending the email.

```
var name = "John";
var link = "http://www.example.com/id="+1;
mailOptions = {
   ...
   html: '<a href="'+ link +'">'+name+'</a>'
};
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use template literals with backtics like this: html: \`<a href=${link}>\`

Comment: @Neekoy yes if he is using ES6

Comment: You are just Awesome!!

Answer (score -4):

You have to read the documentation on the nodemailer website. 
https://nodemailer.com

But here is a straightforward example:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.example.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
  auth: {
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password'
}

// send mail
transporter.sendMail({
  from: 'sender@server.com',
  to: 'receiver@sender.com',
  subject: 'Message title',
  html: '<p>HTML version of the message</p>'
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual solution for the questions?

Comment: You didn't provide any solution